How Do I Make Toolbar Icons the Same Size When the App Runs in Delphi
I don't understand why the toolbar icons while in development environment (RAD Studio) are larger than when the application actual runs.
From the Development Environment:

From when the application runs (the icons are smaller):

Each of the icons are set with a width of 22 and a height of 23. The toolbar button width and height values are the same (22x23 respectively). By changing the forms scaling true or false makes no difference. The development environment is executed with the option "/highdpi:unaware".
Any ideas or other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is due to DPI scaling. Which Delphi version are you using?

I'm using Delphi 12.1. Is there a workable solution or are we stuck with it?

You can always go to Project > Options > Application > Manifest and set "DPI Awareness" to "Unaware" or some other value (try each of them).

Thanks. Setting it to "Unaware" worked perfectly.

Just beware that people with HighDPI screens will have blurry dialogs and graphics as your application will render in 96dpi only to have Windows upscale it to whatecer DPI setting is selected for the monitor upon which the dialog is located. The proper way to solve this is to include the icons in various resolutions so that Delphi can choose the one that matches the DPI setting of the end-user. To do this, use the TImageCollection + TVirtualImageList combo, as descibed in the answer by Torbins.

Standard TImageList does not support scaling of its icons in HiDPI environment. But you can replace it with TVirtualImageList + TImageCollection combo. These components can scale their icons depending on current DPI and even select from multiple icons with different sizes.

I will definitely look into changing out TImageList with the others (TVirtualImageList & TImageCollection). Thanks.
